# Can you use the same 24 word seed from other wallets like ledger nano s to generate a monero address?

Tags: mnemonic-seed, hardware-wallet, ledger

Is the generated 24 word seed from a ledger nano s compatible with monero core wallet?

Comment: What makes matters worse is while the older Electrum v1 list had 1626 words, the list of new Electrum v2 words is the same as the list of 2048 BIP 39 words.  This will confuse end users even more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is **Yes**, but until Monero wallet hardware support is out of alpha testing and is supported by two or more wallets consistently the answer to this question is a work-in-progress.

For example BIP 39/44 technology can be used to seed the synthesis of 25 **Electrum Words**, see [**Example 10**](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin/wiki/Altcoin-Version-Mappings#10-monero-xmr-bip-3944-technology-examples) that uses a shortened **m/44'/128'/0'** path that works with **12**, 15, **18**, 21 and **24** BIP 39 seed words. An older deprecated alpha Monero **Trezor** hardware support never attempted to harmonize BIP 39 technology with Electrum words, which mentally itched me enough to write and share https://github.com/skaht/XMR around 18 months ago. I believe the recent **Nano S** body of work uses a path such as **m/44'/128'/0'/0/0**.

FYSA - The Brainwallet JavaScript code at https://github.com/bholben/seaweed (in alpha) should harmonize brainwallets, BIP 39, and Electrum wallet technologies across the board.

Comment: This question is ultimately related to question of how does one transform 24 BIP 39 seed words and a passphrase to the 25 Electrum v1 seed words used by Monero.  The question posted some time ago at https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/9815/support-for-a-ledger-nano-s-recovery-plan-b remains unanswered.

Answer (score 3):

The list of English words available to create a bitcoin seed is not the same as the list of English words available to create a monero seed.

For example, [the first few words of the former](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/english.txt) are "abandon ability able about" whereas [the first few words of the latter](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/mnemonics/english.h) are  "abbey abducts ability ablaze".

Monero only considers the first three letters of each seed word (for English, four for other languages) - in this case abandon, for example, would result in aba which is not the beginning of any valid monero seed word. That is not going to work well...

And the number of words in each list is not the same either so you could not even convert the words into indices and back.

Comment: If this answer is indeed correct, an implication is that three letters of uniqueness from the 2048 BIP 39 words maps cleanly to 1626 words used by Electrum v1 list of words. I find this to be a far reach due to the amount of error prone time to confirm this is fact.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken monero uses a 25 word seed.

And do you really want to use the same seed on all/multiple wallets?

Comment: The 25th Electrum v1 word used to restore a Monero wallet is always one of the previous 24 words.  There are 1626 Electrun v1 English words that are located within https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/mnemonics/english.h that do not correspond to the 2048 BIP 39 English words posted at https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/english.txt.  The issue is to map the 24 BIP 39 words with a potential passphrase to configure a Ledger to the 25 Electrum v1 words used to restore a Monero wallet without the need to use a Nano device.