# Unable to see my 25 word mnemonic seed?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I have just setup a Monero wallet using my ledger and I would like to write down my 25 word pass phrase so I can back it up.

However, when I go to 'Settings' > 'Seed and Keys' I get nothing, empty box for the mnemonic seed and view and spend  keys are all none sense.

How can I display and backup my seeds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason to use a hardware wallet is so that your seed is safe even if your PC has been compromised. So it's therefore by design that the seed is not visible in the GUI.

You need to back up the Ledger's main seed, which is what your Monero seed is derived from. This is how you will restore access to all funds held in the Ledger if you lose it or it breaks.

You can convert your Ledger seed into your Monero seed using this tool: https://github.com/LedgerHQ/ledger-app-monero/blob/master/tools/python/README.md

Comment: But the ledger seed is 24 words. The Monero seems to be mentioning 25 words. When I generate a wallet using the cli tools, I can see a 25 word seed using the `seed` command, but that is not aware of my ledger.

Comment: @mbilyanov There is a main Ledger seed, from which seeds for Monero and other cryptocurrencies are derived. They're not the same seed. It seems that Ledger do not make it easy to extract the underlying seed/keys that are derived from the main Ledger seed. They make it difficult because the whole point of a hardware wallet is that the private keys should not be used outside of the wallet. See https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005297709-On-which-wallet-can-I-restore-my-wallet-if-I-lose-my-Ledger-device-

Comment: So is it normal that I can't even see the 25 passphrase on my ledger? When I'm inside the Monero APP (the ledger app) and I select to display the 25 word passphrase I just keep scrolling through empty slots. Is that normal?

Comment: @mbilyanov I'm not sure about the app, maybe that's for importing existing Monero seeds you already know about. I just found the exact tool you can use to convert your Ledger seed into a Monero seed: https://github.com/LedgerHQ/ledger-app-monero/blob/master/tools/python/README.md

Answer (score 0):

See the answer at **[URL](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/9815/support-for-a-ledger-nano-s-recovery-plan-b/10922#10922)** for two independent offline techniques to obtain your 25 Monero seed words effectively computed within your Ledger hardware device as long as you have you the 12, 18, or 24 BIP 39 seed words with a possible BIP 39 passphrase used to configure your hardware device.