# Ledger Nano S and seed words

Tags: ledger

On my Ledger Nano S there is a wallet in BTC and a wallet in XMR.
When I created the BTC wallet I wrote down the 24 seed words for restoring the wallet in case of an emergency.

The Monero app installed on Ledger doesn't supply seed words (in this case I assume it should be 25 words instead of 24).
Both the Ledger and in the Monero GUI, the fields for seed words are empty.

Is there anyone that can help clarify the matter?

I have also downloaded the Mnemonic Code Converter tool, but without a guide is very difficult to use (at least for me). I am concerned making a mistake on this issue, could cause the loss of the wallet.

Thanks everybody for you help.
Giovanni

Comment: Did you follow a guide like [this](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/9902/7493) when creating the Monero Ledger wallet? And did you read [this](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/11227/unable-to-see-my-25-word-mnemonic-seed) SE QA before posting?

Comment: Yes I have done all indicated in this guide. 24 seed words created dor BTC hardware ledger account do not work for MONERO GUI.

Comment: The 24 words are your *Ledger* seed. Not for use in the Monero GUI.

Answer (score 2):

This **[URL](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/9815/support-for-a-ledger-nano-s-recovery-plan-b/10922#10922)** provides two independent means for mapping 12, 18, or 24 BIP 39 seed words used to configure Ledger devices to Monero Electrum seed words (25 seed words) that enable other traditional Monero wallets to gain access to your funds.