# LEDGER WITH BTC AND MONERO WALLET

Tags: ledger

0

Hi all,
in my Ledger Nano S there is a wallet in BTC and a wallet in XMR. When I have created BTC wallet I have wrote the 24 seed words for restore wallet in case of emercency. The MONERO APP installed on Ledger token doesn't supply seed words (in this case should be 25 instead of 24). Either on ledger token but also in GUI MONERO DESTOP the fields seed words are empty. Please, is there anyone that can clarify on the matter? I have also downloaded Mnemonic Code Converter tool but without a guide is very difficult to use (at least for me). Making a mistake on this issue could cause the less of the wallet. Thanks everybody for you help. Giovanni

Comment: All your questions should be answered within https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/9815/support-for-a-ledger-nano-s-recovery-plan-b/10922#10922.

Answer (score 1):

When you did set your Ledger Nano S up, you did receive 24 words. Write these down in the correct order and hold them safe (or remember them).

If you install an app for any cryptocurrency (Monero, Bitcoin, Ethereum, ...) on your ledger nano s, your device will make a private key out of your 24 words you got the first time you used your Leder Nano S. This private keys will never leave your device.

If you enter these exacte same 24 words in the same order in another ledger nano s device, you will also have acces to your funds again, if you install the application for a specific ctyptocurrency, as the device wil generate the same private keys out of your 24 words.

If you set up a Monero GUI wallet, you wil do it by using your Ledger Nano S. Select this option in the Monero GUI. Your Ledger Nano S holds the private keys, and these keys wil never be exposed. See the official support page of Ledger for more information about how to set up the Monero GUI.

So you don't need another 24/25 words. Just use your Ledger Nano S.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I have installed MONERO GUI on a virgine PC.

Comment: I have used RESTORE WALLET FROM KEYS ORD MNEMONIC SEED (24 words). This is the result: ELECTRUM STYLE WORD LIST FAILED VERIFICATION.

Comment: Perhaps is it necessary to conver 24 mnemonic words into 25????

Comment: See: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10598/how-do-i-restore-recreate-my-ledger-monero-wallet